# changing the x-axis to string datatype using ticks doesn't work

Tags: flot

Below is my script. Even after using ticks in option the x-axis doesn't change to the specified string. Also how to set from which number y-axis start? Currently it starts at 0.0 but I need it to start at 0.1

```
   var data = [[1, 0.1], [2, 0.2], [3, 0.5], [4, 0.8], [5, 0.8], [6, 0.8], [7, 0.8], [8, 0.9], [9, 1.0], [10, 1.0], [11, 1.0], [12, 1.0]];

        var dataset = [{label: "unit price",data: data}];

        var options = {

            series: {
                lines: { show: true },
                points: {
                    radius: 3,
                    show: true
                },
            xaxis:{ticks: [[1,"foo"], [2,"bar"],  [4,"cat"], [5,"woo"],  [7,"cookie"], [8,"yay"] ]}

            }
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.plot($("#flot-placeholder"), dataset, options);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xaxis` property belongs directly in the top level of the options not under the `series` property.
And for the minimum of an axis you can use the `min` property.

```
var options = {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true
        },
        points: {
            radius: 3,
            show: true
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        ticks: [
            [1, "foo"],
            [2, "bar"],
            [4, "cat"],
            [5, "woo"],
            [7, "cookie"],
            [8, "yay"]
        ]
    },
    yaxis:{
        min: 0.1   
    }
};
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ejey0t7/) for the full example and the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) for more info.